# TFS 2013 Process Templates - Add a new PBI item

Tags: tfs, tfs-process-template

I would like to add new PBI types which display in different colours on the board. 
For example currently there are PBI's which are blue and Bugs which are Red.
I would like to add my own type, 'Performance' (As an example). It will act just like a normal PBI but display in a different colour. This will allow us some quick visual identification of different PBI categories on our Kanban board.

Can any one help me out with this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First I would question the wisdom of adding a new type. Is there some reason that you cant add a "Requirement Type" picklist to the existing PBI that has Performance in the options?

Or maybe you can just use a Tag to signify that it is a performance item?

Adding new work item types complicates queries and confuses users. Bit if you really want to you can follow the MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404855.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the advice I will keep that in mind. The main goal is creating a visual representation on the board. Much like when using Tiago Pascoal Task Board enhancer and marking an item as blocked. It then appears Red on the board. I am also trying to look at how that is done as an alternative we could just Tag the item with a colour.